# Simpson's rule to evaluate Debye's formula in PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7

Question is I have the Debye's formula and need to use Simpson's rule to write a function cv(T) that calculates Cv for a given temperature.
So Cv = 9*V*p*k_B*(T/theta_D)**3 (integral from 0 to theta_D/T) x**4*e**x / (e**x - 1)**2
So for this integral how do I make a function to evaluate the integral using Simpson's method? The integral is 0 to theta_D/T here for the formula.

Here is what I have so far

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from math import e
import numpy as np

# constants
V = 1000                # cm**3 of solid aluminum
p = 6.022*10**28        # number density in m**-3
k_b = 1.380*10**-23     # Boltzmann's constant in J*K**-1
theta_D = 428           # Debye temperature in K
N = 50                  # sample points

def cV(T):    
        return  9*V*p*k_b*(T / theta_D)**3 * (x**4 * e**x / (e**x - 1)**2)

def debye(T, a, b, N):
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework question, you should tag it as such and provide your attempted code for your function `debye`. If this is real life, you're probably better off using [`scipy.integrate.quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) than rolling your own:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def debye(T, a, b):
    return quad(cV, a, b)[0]
```

No need to give the number of quadrature points: `quad` handles this for you. Note that you should define your integrand function, `cV` as a function of `x`, not `T`.